# VBA: An object in a loop is going to "Nothing" and is giving me an "Object variable or With block variable not set" Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with strings and I am going through it to find and correct errors. The following code goes through the column finds the error and replaces it with the correct string.

This is correcting PENNSILVANIA to PENNSYLVANIA.

```
Sub CleanMFG()
    Set Penn = Columns("R").Find(What:="PENNSILVANIA", LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not Penn Is Nothing Then
        Address = Penn.Address
        Do
            Penn.Value = "PENNSYLVANIA"
            Set Penn = Columns("R").FindNext(Penn)
        Loop While Not Penn Is Nothing And Penn.Address <> Address
    End If
```

My problem is that after correcting all the instances of this error, the "Penn" object become Nothing and thus I get an error.

Any ideas on how I can deal with this are appreciated.

Comment: Why not just do a replace: `ActiveSheet.Range("R:R").Replace "PENNSILVANIA","PENNSYLVANIA"` and skip the loop.

Comment: That works for that particular case but for example if I have cells with "Brandon", "Brandon N Clark" or "Brandon &Clark"   and wanted them to be corrected to "Brandon & Clark", by finding all cells that include the word "Brandon" i can correct them all instead of looking at them case by case. That was my logic behind this but maybe your way is simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how Excel evaluates a compound logical statement. Many languages would encounter `Loop While Not Penn Is Nothing` and detect that `Penn Is Nothing` and terminate the loop immediately. Excel VBA evaluates *ALL* parts of the logical check before deciding the logical result. Therefore your error is tripping because `Penn.Address` is actually nothing but is attempting to compare it to `Address`. That's what's throwing the error.

Rewrite your `If` and `Loop` to something like this

```
If Not Penn Is Nothing Then
    Address = Penn.Address
    Do
        Penn.Value = "PENNSYLVANIA"
        Set Penn = Columns("R").FindNext(Penn)
        If Penn Is Nothing Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop While Penn.Address <> Address
End If
```

Comment: In which way this is different from OP?  The exit loop must happen when Penn is nothing.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the indentation and for helping out.
I tried your way but it is still giving me the same error when comparing 
'Penn.Address' to 'Address'.

Comment: Right, please swap the checks. I'm doing this on my mobile phone and didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Find() wraps back to the first found range you could skip the first substitution, loop through all remaining values, exit loop at wrapping back to the first skipped value and finally substitute it

```
Sub CleanMFG()
    Set Penn = Columns("R").Find(What:="PENNSILVANIA", LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not Penn Is Nothing Then
        Address = Penn.Address
        Do
            Set Penn = Columns("R").FindNext(Penn)
            Penn.Value = "PENNSYLVANIA"
        Loop While Not Penn.Address <> Address
        Penn.Value = "PENNSYLVANIA"
    End If
End Sub
```